# How do I configure Windows Firewall to block every host in the local subnet EXCEPT the gateway?

Tags: windows, firewall

I'm attempting to find a way to configure every Windows Firewall on every PC to block every connection of any kind to every host on the local network except the gateway. (It's a subnet full of nothing but workstations)

Ideally, I'd like to do this without Powershell as that is blocked by local policy.

I thought about using GPP, but I can't seem to find a way.

Answer (score 1):

If you enable the Windows Firewall and don't configure any exceptions it will block all unsolicited inbound connections. All outbound connections are allowed by default so the clients will be able to get to the gateway. As all outbound connections are allowed by default a client could attempt to connect to one of the workstations on the local subnet but the Firewall on the other workstation will block it as the traffic will be unsolicited. You can easily enable the Firewall on multiple clients using group policy.

Comment: I never considered defaults. What I'm really worried about isn't unsolicited traffic, but SMBRelay and mDNS spoofing. I want complete blocking, solicited or no. Even if the OS ASKS for something, from the localnet, I want replies ignored.

Comment: I think doing the config using netsh may be your best bet. You could block all other IP's on the LAN except the gateway using this method http://www.itechlounge.net/2014/11/windows-blocking-ip-from-command-line/